Apk Installation blocked by Play Protect
we created a gaming store for the african continent because payment systems used in Africa are not authorized on Play Store.
By default, during the install of the Apk users have a warning but can install anyway.
Today, we have a Play Protect Pop Up without the button to install.
I checked the app on virus total and 0 virus detected. Sha256 here 7b140fc713fef04d93d86f31eed45bbaf152ac6b85cfadcdd59a2a7c5210c122
Please, how could we resolve this ?
I have also opened a ticket, but tired of Google not give a damn about a part of the planet but block people when they're trying to find solutions.


did you read the Guidance about why it could have been blocked? https://developers.google.com/android/play-protect/warning-dev-guidance

Thank you for the link. We use RECEIVE_SMS and READ_SMS to auto-fill OTP. We are trying to remove them right now to see if the apk is still blocked. TY

You can of course get users to turn off play protect scanning of side loader APK files. Settings -> Security -> Play Protect -> Setting (Cog icon) -> turn off scanning and send of apk's to google.

You can try to use SMS Retriever API for sms autofill. It is really simple solution.
This is a link to official documentation
https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/choose-an-api

Thank you very much. We removed the <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" /> <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" /> and now no pop up. Thank you.
